# Include the actual record as a property in Filehelpers record object

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am parsing BgMax file (normal text file separated by rows each property has a specific length in row) with Filehelpers library and I have succesfully created objects and records with FixedLengthRecord. However I would like to store the whole line for each record as a string not only the properties as objects. Is there a neat way like adding a FieldHidden property or something to the Record class so that it saves the whole line there automatically? I also thought to save that line when I am done with creating the Record object but I think it is a bit complicated / not a good idea to do this as I think I need to access the property through reflection.

As an example here is one of the record classes that I use

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowMoreChars)]
   public class StartRecord
   {
      [FieldFixedLength(2)]
      public string PostType;

      [FieldFixedLength(20)]
      public string LayoutName;

      ...

      [FieldFixedLength(1)]
      public string TestMarker;
   }
```

On this StartRecord class I would like to have another string property named Source that will include the whole line before converted into object.
The object is being populated from this code and it is pretty easy to get that line since it the record comes from a foreach loop of list of records.

```
switch (record.Substring(0, 2))
{
   case "01":
       return typeof (StartRecord);                
}
```

So I could maybe populate the property here but I do not like it that much.

Comment: If you need the lines and not the deserialized objects, why not just read the lines of the file instead of objects?
You need to make a more specific question. We have no idea what you FileHelpers library code looks like. Maybe you should add some of your code and it will become clearer?

Comment: The Filehelpers library can be found here http://www.filehelpers.net/ and also in the description of the tag that I used. I included also some code but I think the implementation of doing this is pretty straightforward.

Comment: The "easiest" soultion might be to write something like:
`public Soutrce {get { return PostType + LayoutName + TestMarker}}` and you could of course do reflection. You could modify the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531384/how-to-loop-through-all-the-properties-of-a-class

Comment: I have seen that thread but I would consider that as a last resort method. I would like to see first if it is possible to do it from the class itself and use native FileHelpers decorations.

Comment: Sorry that I have not worked with FileHelpers...
I saw in this thread that filehelpers may parse values into an array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356419/filehelpers-and-csv-what-to-do-when-a-record-can-expand-unbounded-horizontally
Why not parse the row into an array proprerty and then have the properties return the right index of the array: `public string PostType {get {return ArrayProperty[0]}}` and `public string Source {get {String.Join("", ArrayProperty)} }` That way you will have no extra storage needed. The String.Join is probably goo performancewise whithout keeping entire row

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think MarcosMeli answer is what I am looking for, even thought it is not working yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the events interface:

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowMoreChars)]
public class StartRecord
    : INotifyRead
{
  [FieldFixedLength(2)]
  public string PostType;

  ...

  // Field hidden to the lib
  [FieldHidden]
  public string Source;


  public void BeforeRead(BeforeReadEventArgs e)
  {
      this.Source = e.RecordLine;
  }

  public void AfterRead(AfterReadEventArgs e)
  {   
  }

}
```

Comment: I have just tried this. It seems like the correct answer. However the event is not firing and the string remains null. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you reading or writing ? What engine are you using ? what version of the library?

Comment: Reading, version is 3.1.5 (I just got the latest from nuget).